# How to get (X,Y) coordinate of touch in UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView that displays a generated html table.  When the user taps on a cell in the html table, my app needs to know which cell they've tapped, and the (x,y) coordinate of the tap location so I can display a popover at that point.

I've implemented shouldStartLoadWithRequest in my UIWebView delegate.  In my web page, I've embedded javascript code that captures the touch event and passes what should be the (x,y) coordinate of the touched point in a URL request as follows:

```
var x, y;

function init()
{
    // Add an event listener for touch events - set x and y to the coordinate of the touch point
    document.addEventListener('touchstart', function(event) {
        x = event.touches[0].clientX;
        y = event.touches[0].clientY;
    }, false);
}

function cellTapped(event)
{
    window.location.href="file://myapp/dostuff?x=" + x + "&y=" + y;
}
```

In my html table, each cell gets an onclick event that calls cellTapped():

```
<td onclick="cellTapped(event)">...</td>
```

So whenever the user touches anywhere in the UIWebView, I get the coordinate of the touch point, which I save off in x and y.  If they touch within one of the table cells, I receive the touch event (which sets x and y), then cellTapped() gets called and I set window.location.href, passing the (x,y) coordinate into my app.

This all works beautifully.  Unless the user has zoomed or scrolled the UIWebView.  When they zoom or scroll, the x and y coordinates I'm getting from event.touches[0].clientX and event.touches[0].clientY are off by some varying number of pixels (varies with the amount of zoom and how far up/down or left/right the web view is scrolled).

Is there some way to determine the zoom ratio and scroll position of the web view so that I can adjust my x and y coordinates accordingly?  The `zoomScale` and `contentOffset` properties from UIScrollView do not seem to be exposed in UIWebView.

Comment: Take a look at: [How to detect zoom scale of UIWebView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449744/how-to-detect-zoom-scale-of-uiwebview) and [How can I get the current zoom level in a UIScrollView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451071/how-can-i-get-the-current-zoom-level-in-a-uiscrollview?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**:  In iOS 5 and above, the scrollView property of UIWebView is exposed and accessible so this becomes a non-issue.  In my case, I still need to support devices running iOS 4 (believe it or not...), so the following solves it for older versions.

By looping through the subviews of my `UIWebView`, I can find the underlying `UIScrollView`, then use its `zoomScale` and `contentOffset` properties to find the zoom and scroll position:

```
for (UIView *view in myWebView.subviews) 
{
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) 
    {
        // Get UIScrollView object
        scrollview = (UIScrollView *) view;

        // Find the zoom and scroll offsets
        float zoom = scrollView.zoomScale;
        float xOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.x;
        float yOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    }
}
```

I don't know if Apple would approve of this for app store submission, since I assume they had their reasons for not exposing the underlying `UIScrollView` object, but it does solve my problem.  My app is distributed under an Enterprise license anyway, so app store submission isn't an issue for me.

Comment: Is the `-[UIWebView scrollView]` property not what you want? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIWebView/scrollView

Comment: @axiixc: I still need to support devices running iOS 4 (I know, I know...), and the scrollView property is only available on iOS 5 and above.  I've made an edit to clarify this.

Answer (score 2):

Use UIGestureRecognizerDelegate method:

Add UIGestureRecognizerDelegate in declaration file (i.e. your .h file)

Step 1: Just set the delegate of gestureRecognizer: (in .m file)

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *webViewTapped = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapAction:)];
webViewTapped.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
webViewTapped.delegate = self;
[webView addGestureRecognizer:webViewTapped];
[webViewTapped release];
```

Step 2: Override this function: (in .m file)

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```

Step 3: Now implement the tapAction function:

```
- (void)tapAction:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{    
    CGPoint point = [sender locationInView:self.view]; // get x and y from here
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can do that on a UIWebView because the web view intercepts the tap before the gesture recognizer ever sees it.

Comment: Tried.  The tapAction never gets called because the UIWebView intercepts the tap and does not propagate it.